# Liferay company logo config

Tags: java, css

I'm trying to version control my liferay instance, and I'm not seeing where the company logo is set. When I uploaded it through the admin console, I see it was created as `11502.gif` in the `data/`, but I can find no configuration file referencing it.

Where is this stored, and is it versionable?

Answer (score -1):

You haven't stated which version, but in 6.0.5+, you change the company logo from:

Control Panel (dockbar) -> Portal -> Portal Settings (left menu) -> Display Settings (right menu)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. This puts the data in the database.

Comment: It looks like I can just hack into the banner and change the image from a theme, however. That should work.